# Class diagram tool able to display comments?

Tags: uml, visualization, class-diagram, dia

I'm creating a class diagram. The purpose is *communication and visualisation*, not code generation or other processing, so I don't have to stick to UML rules.

I made a quick starting point with Dia, a program that I have some experience using. While it is really easy to use, it's a bit... lacking in aesthetics and functionality after all. So I downloaded and tried [Modelio](http://www.modelio.org/), [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/), [WhiteStarUML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/whitestaruml/) and [Violet](http://alexdp.free.fr/violetumleditor/page.php). They're all nice but don't have one feature I'd like to have.

In Dia, I'm able to simply add a comment to any class or member and show it beside the element (see picture). It makes it possible to create really informative diagrams for humans. In these other four tools I'm able to bury some documentation inside the objects to show up in a window when they're doubleclicked but it's a lot clunkier than having it visible right away. A UML note is fine with classes, but it doesn't work for smaller elements.

What diagramming tool has a way to convey informal information while still offering useful tools for structured diagrams? I certainly don't need the full set of UML intricacies, especially the non-visible (like unique or ordered collections etc.), but also more than just arrows and boxes.

[image: The diagram]

Comment: I am using Dia too, but if I am only creating things for a presentation in which graphical understanding is of greater importance, then am I using LibreOffice Draw.

Comment: Draw and Inkscape and the like are great tools for presenting stuff, but a tiny bit ineffective when making larger diagrams. Or modifying them, because many things have to be done manually.

Comment: What you want is not a part of the object model of Dia and I do not know of any other tool that is capable of that. The only solution I see right now is to export the diagram to svg and use gedit for adding the information you want manually. Maybe can you take a look at MindMapping tools, specifically those that can import svg files.

Answer (score 1):

In [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html) you can show the comments of an element its own section.

[image: Class with comment]

Comments of features cannot be shown inline, but you can add a note that shows the comments of a specific feature.

Answer (score 0):

Not only on class diagrams, but on all UML diagrams it is the common element and it is called Note. Very important one, really.

[image]

Up to the standard, you can write something to any element, but this something will never be comments. Except the case of Note.

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned UML notes already in my question. They're fine and handy with shapes but can't be linked to inner member elements for which I need to have descriptions too. And, in my opinion, they look a bit less elegant than "inline comments".

Comment: As for tools, in VP UML you can type content of the Class line by line, and if you start the lines by //, they won't be realized in code, or you can define terms by thesaurus. But ***all these options are OUT of UML standard.*** But I have said it already in the answer.

Comment: @neonblitzer Imagine, how your "comments" will work while code generation!